# Pickle persistence file needs to be deleted for telegram bot to work

Tags: python, persistence, pickle, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am using the PicklePersistence example provided in python telegram bot github.

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/persistentconversationbot.py

Sometimes the bot doesn't /start. After troubleshooting, I discovered that the problem is caused by the pickle persistence file. To get /start to work, I had to delete persistence file. It seems the persistence file is corrupted.

What can be done to make the pickle persistence file more robust against corruption?

I am using python telegram bot 12.4.2 and python v3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

The reason /start cannot be reentered is due to the state machine of the bot. Because persistence was turned on, this state is always remembered even after the bot is shut down and restarted.

The solution to fix my problem was to set `allow_reentry` to True. Verified to work in my case.

https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html